# Calculate Integral of $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ on the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with Riemann sums

Tags: multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

I need to calculate the integral of $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ on the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ by using the definition of Riemann Sums. I know with Fubini that it has to be $\frac{7}{6} $ but in my solution I get $\frac{1}{2} $. Where is my mistake?

Let $z_k$ be a partition of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with $z_k=z_1 \times z_2$ and $z_1=\{0,1/k,2/k,...,1\}$ and $z_2=\{0,1/k,2/k,...,1\}$

$x_{ij} \in [(i-1)/k,i/k]\times[(j-1)/k,j/k]$ from wehre we choose $x_{ij}=(i/k,j/k)$

Then:
\begin{align}
S_{z_k}(f)&=\sum_{i,j=1}^k(i/k+j/k)^2\cdot1/k^2\\
&=1/k^4 (\sum_{i=1}^k i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^kij+\sum_{j=1}^kj^2\\
&=1/k^4((1/3)(k(k+1)(2k+1)+(1/2)k^2(k+1)^2)\\
&=1/2+5/(3k)+3/(2k^2)+1/(3k^3) \rightarrow 1/2
\end{align}
for $k$ to infinity.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I would like to see how you go from summatories to k-formulas.

Comment: the last equation is wrong, you miss a $\sum_j$ for $\sum_i i^2$,so is $sum_i$ missing for $\sum_j j^2$,add them and you get2/3+1/2=7/6

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your sum $S_{z_{k}}(f)$:

\begin{align}
S_{z_{k}}(f) &= \sum_{i,j=1}^{k}(i/k+j/k)^{2}\times 1/k^{2} \tag{1}\\
             &= \frac{1}{k^{4}}\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{k}i^{2} + 2\sum_{i,j=1}^{k} ij + \sum_{i,j=1}^{k} j^{2}\right) \tag{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{k^{4}}\left( k \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} +\frac{k^{2}(k+1)^{2}}{2}+k\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}\right) \tag{3}
\end{align}

After simplifying and letting $k\to \infty$: we obtain
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{7}{6}.$$

---

To point out where your mistake is: You go from $(1)$ above to
$$\frac{1}{k^{4}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^{2} + 2\sum_{i,j=1}^{k}ij + \sum_{j=1}^{k} j^{2}\right)$$
which is incorrect because you are missing a summation over $j$ in the first term $"\sum_{i=1}^{k} i^{2}"$ and similarly you miss a summation over $i$ in the last term $"\sum_{j=1}^{k} j^{2}$" (compare with $(2)$). Leaving out these summations have the effect that when $k\to \infty$ neither of the aforementioned terms contribute to the end result.

Comment: In your third equation with k(k+1)(2k+1)/6 why is there k*k*(k+1)(2k+1)/6. Why are there two k?

Comment: We know that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^{2} = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$ so $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{k} i^{2} = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} = k \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Oh thank you very much !! :))

Comment: @Blue2001 Happy to help, sorry for missing your question where your mistake is! I have added it now in case you are still wondering.

Answer (score 1):

the last equation($\sum_{i,j=1}^k(i/k+j/k)^2\cdot1/k^2\\
=1/k^4 (\sum_{i=1}^k i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^kij+\sum_{j=1}^kj^2$)
is wrong, RHS you miss a $\sum_j $for $\sum_i i^2$,so is $\sum_i $missing for $\sum_j j^2$,add them and you get$\frac23+\frac12=\frac76 $

Comment: At which position exactly. I can't see it :/